# How do I count the number of files with a specific extension on Android?

Tags: java, android, file-io, file, filesystems

In the app I'm developing for Android I'm letting users create files specific to my application with the extension ".rbc". So far I have been successful in creating, writing to, and reading from these files.

Right now I am trying to count the number of these files that exists. I'm not particularly familiar with Java and I'm just beginning programming for Android so I feel a bit lost. All of my attempts so far at doing this have not been able to locate any files with my extension.

So I basically have two questions I need answered so that I can figure this out:

Where is the default directory where Android stores files created by an application?

Do you have any examples do you can give me of counting files with a specific extension on Android?

Thank you very much in advance for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some tests showed me that the default directory where Android stores files created by an application using `Context.getFilesDir()` is `/data/data/<your_package_name>/files`

To count the files in any given directory you use `File.listFiles(FileFilter)` over the root dir. Your FileFilter should then be something like this (to filter for ".rbc" files):

```
public static class RBCFileFilter implements FileFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        String suffix = ".rbc";
        if( pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(suffix) ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

If you have some kind of directory structure you need to recursively search then you will have to `File.listFiles(FileFilter)` over the entire directory structure. And it should be something like:

```
public static List<File> listFiles(File rootDir, FileFilter filter, boolean recursive) {
    List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
    if( !rootDir.exists() || !rootDir.isDirectory() ) 
        return result;


    //Add all files that comply with the given filter
    File[] files = rootDir.listFiles(filter);
    for( File f : files) {
        if( !result.contains(f) )
            result.add(f);
    }

    //Recurse through all available dirs if we are scanning recursively
    if( recursive ) {
        File[] dirs = rootDir.listFiles(new DirFilter());
        for( File f : dirs ) {
            if( f.canRead() ) {
                result.addAll(listFiles(f, filter, recursive));
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

And where `DirFilter` would implements `FileFilter` this way:

```
public static class DirFilter implements FileFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        if( pathname.isDirectory() ) 
            return true;

        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Android usually stores files created by an application in data/data/package_name_of_launching_Activity and there you'll find a few folders where files can be stored. You can get a cache directory within that path by calling getCacheDir().

A quick strategy for counting specific extensions could be as follows:

If you have a folder, say `File folder = new File(folderPath)` where folderPath is the absolute path to a folder. You could do the following:

```
String[] fileNames = folder.list();
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i< filenames.length; i++)
{
  if (filenames[i].contains(".rbc"))
    {
      total++;
     }
  }
```

This can give you a count of the total files with ".rbc" as the extension. Although this may not be the best/efficient way of doing it, it still works.

Comment: It must be pointed out that `Context.getCacheDir()` gives you the location of `/data/data/<package-name>/cache` and `Context.getFilesDir()` points to `/data/data/<package-name>/files`. The former is flushed regularly so be aware when storing files in the cache dir.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a java 8+ example:

```
var total=Arrays.asList(new File(pathToDirectory).list())
                      .stream()
                      .filter(x -> x.contains(".rbc"))
                      .collect(Collectors.counting());
```

or

```
var fileNames = Arrays.asList(tempDir.list())
                       .stream()
                       .filter(x -> x.contains(".rbc"))
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
var total=fileNames.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

For counting files you can try this code:

```
# public static List getFiles(File aStartingDir)   
# {  
#     List result = new ArrayList();  
#    
#     File[] filesAndDirs = aStartingDir.listFiles();  
#     List filesDirs = Arrays.asList(filesAndDirs);  
#     Iterator filesIter = filesDirs.iterator();  
#     File file = null;  
#     while ( filesIter.hasNext() ) {  
#       file = (File)filesIter.next();  
#       result.add(file); //always add, even if directory  
#       if (!file.isFile()) {  
#         //must be a directory  
#         //recursive call!  
#         List deeperList = getFileListing(file);  
#         result.addAll(deeperList);  
#       }  
#    
#     }  
#     Collections.sort(result);  
#     return result;  
#   }
```

You can use fileFilter parameter for listFiles() method to return files with .rbc extension.

EDIT: Sorry, missed one question. Files will be placed in your application package which will be there in
data/data.. You can view them in File Explorer in Eclipse with DDMS mode.

Comment: What class is listFiles() a method of?