# Android: File list in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I need do the file list in ListView. Files from the folder (.txt files).
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this [link](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Creating-Lists-Using-The-Android-Listactivity/)

use

```
File mfile=new File("/sdcard");
File[] list=mfile.listFiles();
```

and filter in loop using

```
if(name.endsWith(".txt")) { }
```

[How to list all files and folders locating on sd card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638293/how-to-list-all-files-and-folders-locating-on-sd-card)

[How do I count the number of files with a specific extension on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058934/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-files-with-a-specific-extension-on-android)