# How to select jpeg images rom android gallery?

Tags: java, android, image, jpeg

I need to create a App where I open Android Gallery from my Android App and I should be able to view only .jpeg images in gallery, other images like .png or any other format should be removed .

Can someone please suggest how to do this ?

Comment: Where is your work? Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

look this example for txt you can do the same with jpg files, just list the files and select only that you want to use. [Android: File list in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275668/android-file-list-in-listview).
NOTE: The folder for gallery is Enviroment.DIRECTORY_DCIM

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
intent.setType("image/jpeg");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
Main.this.startActivity(intent);
```

but not sure if all android galery apps would honor the type extra

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...

```
// Directory path here
String path = "PATH/TO/GALLERY"; 
File folder = new File(path);
File[] directoryListing = folder.listFiles(); 
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
        if (files.endsWith(".JPG") || files.endsWith(".JPEG")) {
           // Handle your file here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/jpg");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);    

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

    switch(requestCode) { 
    case 1:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        }
    }
}
```